# Why can't I download wsdl file using SSIS

Tags: soap, ssis

I'm trying to download WSDL file using SSIS. On my laptop it works fine but on the server it throws an error: SSL certiciate response obtained from the server was not valid. Cannot process the request.
The error indicates that there was an issue with the SSL certificate presented by the server during an HTTPS (secure) connection. When a client (SSIS package) makes an HTTPS request to a server, it expects a valid SSL certificate to establish a secure and trusted connection.
Since the problem is on the server a client is trying to make an HTTPS request to, I can't make head nor tail while it works on my laptop but throws an error on another host.

Got any idea?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Best guess is that the server has been patched and somewhat in the near past, older security stuff got flagged as insecure (TLS 1.1, 1.2?) Something like that. Anyways, you either needed to flip registry settings to say Sure, use insecure-secure communication channel or you update your code to use the current TLS/cipher something. Given that you're using the out of the box component, I think you're stuck trying to figure out the registry approach